# How can I add mail from a local host to the list of Outlook _Safe Senders_?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, bugzilla

We have an application (Bugzilla) running on a server local to our network. The email that is send out is from bugzilla-daemon@ourprojbugz (notice that there are no domain qualifiers such as .com or .org). When I try to add this address to the list of *Safe Senders* I get a warning popup that says:

> The e-mail address or domain name you entered is not valid.
>   Valid entries include: someone@example.com or example.com

Microsoft is trying to be helpful here (because most email comes from hosts that have some sort of top level domain identifier).

Our network is set up so that we get to the bugzilla database using the URL:

> http://ourprojbugz/cgi-bin/bugzilla3/index.cgi

I have tried using the *Never Block Sender* option from the *Delete* section of the *Home* menu, and also tried adding it manually in the *Safe Senders* tab of the *Junk E-mail Options* form.

Is there some way to add email from a local host (one that is not qualified by a Top Level Domain name)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the *Junk* filters, you can create a *rule* to do this.

***Rules*** (in the *Move* section of the *Home* menu) can be used to move mail from a specific sender to a specified mail folder.

Open a message from the sender (in this example, *bugzilla-daemon@ourprojbugz*). When the message is open, select the *Rules* in the *Move* section of the *Home* menu and create a rule.

In the *When I get e-mail ...* section of the *Create Rule* form, check the box to select *From bugzilla-daemon@ourprojbugz*

In the *Do the following* section of the *Create Rule* form, check the box for *Move the item to folder:*, and select the folder you want the mail to go into.

Answer (score 0):

It is stored in the registry:

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook`

(Or the profile name). It is stored in binary – I confirmed that there was a write to this location via `ProcMon` against `OUTLOOK.EXE`.

Your host should have an FQDN if its going to send email anyways even local, can you not add `.local` or `.lan` to this host's name? If using a Red Hat derivitive it would be in `/etc/sysconfig/network`.